# Ist "wegen dir" falsch und nur "deinetwegen" richtig?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich habe Widersprüchliches darüber gelesen, ob die Verwendung der Präposition `wegen` + `Pronomen im Dativ` richtig oder falsch ist.

> wegen mir, wegen dir, wegen ihm, wegen ihr usw.

Viele Leute behaupten, richtig sei nur

> meinetwegen, deinetwegen, ihretwegen, seinetwegen usw.

weil die Präposition den 2. Fall verlange *("Wegen des Sturms musste die Feier abgesagt werden.")*.

Ist das wahr?

Comment: Logischerweise sind _wegen meiner_, _wegen deiner_ und _wegen seiner_ gültig, mit den Personalpronomen im Wesfall. Hört man aber nicht, oder?

Comment: @misterben *wegen meiner/deiner* etc. habe ich noch nie gehört und klingen in meinen Ohren auch falsch: "Sie kam wegen meiner zum Fest." ?!?

Comment: @splattne: In altertümlichen Texten findet sich das mitunter. Im DWB findet sich auch z.B. *von m[e]iner wegen* bzw. *von s[e]iner wegen*.

Comment: Klar, in alten Zeiten war vieles anders, weil sich jede Sprache fortlaufend verändert und sich aufgrund verschiedener Einflüsse (weiter)entwickelt.

Comment: @splattne: klingt "Sie kam wegen meiner Einladung zum Fest." besser?

Comment: @bjoernz ja, ist rein grammatikalisch sowieso richtig, weil "meiner" = Genitiv (ich, meiner, mir, mich)

Comment: Ich habe ein bounty für diese Frage eröffnet, weil es schön wäre, wenn jemand eine gute Zusammenfassung der Argumente von Zwiebelfisch und Belles lettres schreibt. Weil das aber viel Arbeit ist, finde ich 100 extra Reputation angemessen.

Comment: @thei: Es braucht keine Zusammenfassung von Zwiebelfisch, Bastian Sick liegt schlicht und einfach falsch. Ich habe aber meine Antwort noch etwas ausgebaut.

Comment: 's Pferd vum Bauer ...
oder am Bauer sei Ferd ... beides ist gut, weil verständlich. Für mich falsch wäre: 's Bauers Pferd. So spricht nur ein Gaul!

Comment: @misterben: Mein Fahrlehrer hat immer *wegs meiner* also standarddeutsch *wegen meiner* gesagt. Ab und an hört man es also im tiefsten Bayern ;)

Answer (score 24):

Wegen dir hab ich das jetzt gegoogelt und 'wegen dir' ist ganz klar nicht falsch!

---

Auf http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wegen-genitiv-dativ.php wird verständlich erklärt, warum das so ist:

> Die Herkunft von wegen als
>   nieder­deut­sches Sub­stan­tiv ist
>   nicht mehr prä­sent[...]. Wegen ge­hört daher
>   zu den echten Prä­posi­tio­nen. Sie
>   kön­nen nur mit dem Dativ oder dem
>   Akku­sa­tiv ste­hen und grundsätzlich
>   nicht mit dem Geni­tiv. Der kor­rek­te
>   und stili­stisch bes­sere An­schluß an
>   wegen ist also der Dativ.

Weiter unten steht dann auch noch als Reaktion auf [Bastian Sick's fälschliche Kritik](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,267725,00.html) dies:

> Offenkundig hat Bastian Sick den
>   Unter­schied zwi­schen Hoch­deutsch
>   und Stan­dard­deutsch nicht
>   verstanden. Er ver­wech­selt die
>   bei­den Be­grif­fe. Das Bairi­sche ist
>   seit jeher einer der Haupt­dia­lek­te
>   des Hoch­deut­schen. Die Wen­dung
>   we­gen dir kann nach al­lem, was
>   bis­her ge­sagt wur­de, auf kei­nen
>   Fall falsch sein. Sie mutet dennoch
>   aus der Sicht eines Nord­deut­schen
>   dia­lek­tal an. Das liegt daran, daß
>   sich be­reits eine an­de­re Fügung
>   gebildet hat, noch bevor wegen zu
>   einer hoch­deut­schen Prä­posi­tion
>   wurde: meinet­wegen, deinet­wegen,
>   seinet­wegen usw.

Die präzise Antwort auf die gestellte Frage ist also:

**Das ist nicht wahr! Die Benutzung des Dativs ist richtig.**

Comment: Dazu sagt der Duden: "[Wegen steht] Standardsprachlich mit Dativ in bestimmten Verbindungen und wenn bei Pluralformen der Genitiv nicht erkennbar ist", ansonsten standardsprachlich immer mit Genitiv.

Comment: @OregonGhost: was dem Artikel ja nicht widerspricht... Standarddeutsch vs. Hochdeutsch etc.

Comment: „… und sogar angebrachter als die Benutzung des Genitivs“ in Bezug auf die Frage ist etwas irreführend, da „deinetwegen“ ja wie im Artikel erläutert gar kein Genitiv ist, sondern auf ein Possesivpronomen im Dativ (*von deinen Wegen*) zurück geht. Insofern kam in der Frage ja gar nie eine Genitivform vor, die es zu diskutieren galt.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod. :-)

Answer (score 20):

Ich bin ein wenig überrascht, dass bei dieser interessanten Frage als Quellen ausschließlich Bastian Sick und belleslettres herhalten müssen. Nichts gegen diese beiden Quellen, nur scheinen sie hier unterschiedlicher Meinung zu sein. Das kann vorkommen.

Laut [belleslettres](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/genitiv/wegen-genitiv-dativ.php) gehört *wegen* zu den "echten Präpositionen" und wird daher mit Dativ verwendet. Ich weiß nicht, was "echte" und "unechte" Präpositionen unterscheidet, aber laut [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/) gibt es eine stattliche Anzahl von [Präpositionen, die mit Genetiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html) verwendet werden. Darunter auch *[wegen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-wegen-58500)*.

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wegen_infolge_bezueglich) betrachtet die Form "wegen mir" als umgangssprachlich. Er behauptet, dass der Dativ nur "in bestimmten Verbindungen und wenn bei Pluralformen der Genitiv nicht erkennbar ist" verwendet wird. Ansonsten zeigt auch die Auflistung der Beispiele die Verwendung mit Genitiv.

Diese Ansicht scheint [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wegen) zu teilen:

> Präp.; mit Gen.; auch nachgestellt
>   Präp.; mit Dat. umgangssprachlich, süddeutsch, österreichisch

Die Entscheidung, ob das nun falsch oder richtig ist, überlasse ich dem geneigten Leser.

Answer (score 13):

Richtig und falsch ist sowieso immer so eine Sache. Und gerade in einer solchen Auseinandersetzung kommt es stark auf die Region an, in der du dich gerade befindest.

Wenn man mal davon ausgeht, dass die Verhaltensweisen in der Wahl zwischen *deinetwegen* und *wegen dir* auf *meinetwegen* und *wegen mir* übertragbar sind, dann gibt der **Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache** über die tatsächliche Verwendung im deutschsprachigen Raum Auskunft.

[image]
*Quelle: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f12d/*

Gut zu erkennen ist, dass

- *Wegen mir* am verbreitetsten zu sein scheint und
- *Meinetwegen* eher im norddeutschen Raum verbreitet ist.

Comment: Mein Vater sagt "mir wegen"

Answer (score 5):

Streng genommen: Ja, es ist falsch. Leider ist *wegen dir* mittlerweile so enorm oft benutzt, gehört und gelesen worden, dass es kaum noch einem auffällt.

*wegen* verlangt einen Genitiv. Das kann man besonders schön daran erkennen, dass es **DESwegen** heißt und nicht **DEMwegen**.

*wegen dir* ist Umgangssprache, auch wenn es angeblich schon im Duden stehen soll und damit anerkanntes Hochdeutsch ist (konnte aber keine Quelle finden).

Lustigerweise benutzen viele **ihretwegen** richtig … verrückte Deutsche.

Ein sehr guter Artikel dazu: [Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,267725,00.html)

---

Das gleiche Problem hat auch *dieses Jahres*.

Es ist, wie gesagt, streng grammatikalisch gesehen falsch - wirklich beschweren wird sich aber kaum jemand, zumindest nicht in der gesprochenen Sprache. Wahrscheinlich wird man bei richtiger Aussprache sogar schräg angeschaut.

Die beiden oberen Beispiele sind ähnliche Fälle. Man hört fast nur noch "diesen Jahres", obwohl das Genitiv-s am "Jahr" schon stutzig machen sollte. Richtig heißt es nun mal "dieses Jahres". Ein schöner Artikel dazu vom Zwiebelfisch: [Das Verflixte dieses Jahres](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,281668,00.html)

Comment: *diesen Jahres* kann ich langsam auch nicht mehr sehen... Genau wie *in 2011*, aber das ist ja kein Genitivproblem :)

Comment: Hier noch ein Zwiebelfisch-Link zum Thema "wegen dir": http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,267725,00.html

Comment: Nein, es ist nicht falsch. Es mag nicht das höchste [Register](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28Linguistik%29) sein, aber innerhalb dieses Registers is es nie und nimmer "grammatikalisch gesehen falsch". Bitte in keinen unbegründeten Preskriptivismus abrutschen. [Grammatik](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatik) heißt "so funktioniert die Sprache tatsächlich", und nicht "so sollte sie meines Erachtens funktionieren".

Comment: Diese Antwort ist schlicht falsch. Downvote. http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wegen-genitiv-dativ.php

Comment: This is one of the "holy grails" of German everyday language. If you don't want to hear looooong lectures about it from some people, use the correct one. You might sound a bit posh to other ones, but that's better than the lectures, believe me! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Nach meiner Erfahrung wird *wegen dir*, *wegen mir* und so weiter vor allem im süddeutschen Raum verwendet und ist dort auch, zumindest umgangssprachlich, korrekt. Das ist aber nur meine Vermutung.

Das Problem wird [im Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,267725,00.html) erläutert, dort jedoch allgemeiner (na, halt *der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod*).

Für meine Ohren klingt *wegen dir* falsch, *deinetwegen* hingegen richtig. Es ist also vermutlich auch eine subjektive und teils regionale Angelegenheit, siehe dazu auch die Antwort von bernd_k und den dortigen Kommentar von splattne.

Answer (score 5):

Faustregel, um Streit zu vermeiden: "Wegen dir" bzw. generell "wegen" mit Dativ nur in Süd- und Mitteldeutschland benutzen. ;-)

Ob es richtig oder falsch ist, darüber streiten sich die Geister... Duden vs. Bastian Sick vs. Belles Lettres... offensichtlich nicht so einfach, die Sache.

Answer (score 4):

Ich komme aus Schleswig-Holstein und verwende beides:
z.B.:

> Wegen Dir kann ich nicht zum Konzert gehen!
>   Das mache ich nur deinetwegen.

Wegen Dir: ist gebräuchlich aber eher als Anklage gemeint.

Answer (score 1):

Ich empfinde

> **wegen dir**

als korrekt.
Hingegen klingt

> **wegen Ihnen**

falsch.

Comment: Du lebst nicht in Österreich, oder? Dort klingt auch das zweite Beispiel nicht falsch (meine Meinung).

Comment: Richtig erkannt ich komme aus DE.

Comment: Was willt du eigentlich statt "wegen Ihnen" sagen?

Comment: _Ihretwegen_ ist eine Alternative, die zwar sowohl  _wegen Ihnen_ wie auch _wegen ihr_ bedeuten kann, mir aber leichter über die Lippen geht.

Comment: Ich lebe in Österreich, aber "wegen Ihnen" klingt schon ein bisschen hatschert für mich.

Answer (score 1):

Als Liedtitel ist "Wegen Dir" zumindest einschlägig.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2ErWsQi-tY
Die Ärzte - Wegen Dir

Comment: Vgl. dazu: Niki "Wegen dir" (1986). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQur7Eh-TGg WARNUNG: Ich übernehme keine Haftung für evtl. auftretende Augen- und Ohrenschädigungen. ;)

Comment: Im Booklet zu "Das Beste Von Kurz Nach Früher Bis Jetze" schreiben sie aber auch, dass sie wegen dem Titel (:p) böse Briefe bekommen haben, weil es falsch sei ;)

Answer (score -3):

In Österreich* gibts da ein Sprichwort das sagt: "Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod." Grammatikalisch richtig wäre natürlich "Der Dativ ist des Genitivs Todes" (oder so ähnlich) aber das ist ja genau der Witz an dem Sprichwort, dass der Dativ fälschlicherweise verwendet wird, obwohl Genitiv gehören würde. Denn der Dativ ist tatsächlich dem Genitiv sein Tod!

Praktisch ist es heutzutage so, dass der Genitiv in der Umgangssprache fast nicht mehr benutzt wird. (Die Mitvergangenheit ist beim gesprochenen Wort auch schon fast ausgestorben*, in Büchern findet man sie aber noch oft. Und für Deutschaufsätze braucht man sie.)

Ich denke, dass es sich hier um einen Punkt handelt, wo sich die deutsche Hochsprache klar von der Umgangssprache unterscheidet.

Meine Antwort lautet daher: Wenn man davon ausgeht, dass die Hochsprache richtig und die Umgangssprache falsch ist, lautet die Antwort klar: "nur deinetwegen und meinetwegen ist richtig, nicht aber 'wegen mir' oder 'wegen dir'". Wenn man davon ausgeht, dass die Umgangssprache auch "wahr" ist, dann ist auch "wegen dir" und "wegen mir" richtig. Die Antwort läuft also darauf hinaus, ob die Umgangssprache nun eine "richtige" Sprache ist oder nicht. Das aber kann ich seriös nicht beantworten.

Meiner Meinung nach ist "wegen dir" und "wegen mir" sehr wohl richtig! Ich bin nämlich der Meinung, dass es eher problematisch wäre, die Umgangssprache als etwas minderwertiges zu betrachten.

*In Deutschland ist es vielleicht ähnlich oder auch anders, aber ich bin aus Österreich und deshalb spreche ich davon.

ENDE_DER_ERÖRTERUNG

Comment: Eben falsch. Und es heisst "Der Dativ ist des Genitivs Tod." oder "Der Dativ ist der Tod des Genitivs."

Comment: "Der Dativ ist des Genitivs Tod" sagt aber kein Mensch.

Comment: @Michael
> aber das ist ja genau der Witz an dem Sprichwort, dass der Dativ
> fälschlicherweise verwendet wird, obwohl Genitiv gehören würde. Ich stimm zu, dass dies ein Witz sein soll. Aber anscheinend ist die Fassung, in der der Dativ vorkommt, korrekt… hier ist es gemeint, dass der Dativ bzgl. des Genitivs der (oder ja: *sein*) Tod sei. D. h. die Anwendung des Dativs drückt eher eine *Verhältnis* zu dem Genitiv, als ein *Eigentum* des Genitivs aus.

Comment: @RS: Eigentum ist aber genau das: Ein Verhältnis (Besitzverhältnis).