# Genitive preposition "wegen" and personal pronouns

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, preposition, genitive, personal-pronoun

I am wondering how to correctly form a genitive construction in German while translating a sentence from English to German.

For example:

English:

> It is broken because of you.

German:

> Es ist kaputt wegen (?)

I do not know what pronoun to put here. I am aware that one can use the dative in this situation, but I need to know the correct pronoun in the genitive for this sentence.

Use of *wegen* as a genitive preposition is required.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/329

Comment: by the way. a very good reference for inflections is [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"correct" (most widely used) solution here is:

```
Es ist kaputt wegen *dir*.(which is dative)
Es ist *deinetwegen* kaputt.(which uses an adverb)
```

correct genitive were: *deiner*

```
Es ist kaputt wegen *deiner*
```

*"wegen deiner"* mostly gets replaced by the adverb *"deinetwegen"* in spoken language, if there is not some object *deiner* can refer to.

If some object is given native speakers mostly use:

```
Es ist kaputt wegen *deines Fehlers*.  
It is broken because of your error.(or whateverm might have happened)
```

You ran into a currently changing construction there.
citing from the [linked question:](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/329/ist-wegen-dir-falsch-und-nur-deinetwegen-richtig) (bolding by me)

> Sie ["authentic" pronouns like "wegen"] kön­nen **nur** mit dem Dativ oder dem Akku­sa­tiv ste­hen und grundsätzlich **nicht mit dem Geni­tiv.**

and again citing from linked question:

> Anzahl von [Präpositionen, die mit Genetiv](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html) verwendet werden. Darunter auch [wegen.](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Genitiv.html#Anchor-wegen-58500)

Your example is awkwardly chosen. As visible in the canoo.net article there in fact are constructions with genitive, but almost noone uses the really correct way in speech, because it seemingly sounds "awkward"...

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is just wrong. Deinetwegen < von deinetwegen < von deinen wegen (nhd. von deiner Seite), which is dative (von only goes with dative).

Comment: It may be interesting to know that the phrase "wegen mir" is (at least in southern Germany, Austria and Switzerland) means something like "fine with me, I don't really care". Similar expressions are "meinetwegen" or "von mir aus". A conversation could go like this: "Können wir auf dem Weg beim Bäcker anhalten?" - "Wegen mir." You can imagine a short shrug with the answer. So, if you put the example in the question as "Es ist kaputt wegen mir", it doesn't necessarily come across as that apologetic and remorseful ;)